# How do you "re-include" a file that was excluded from source control?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I excluded a file from source control a week ago, and I would like to re-include it into my VS 2010 project.

I can't find a single way to do this, I am completely stumped.  I deleted the file, checked everything in, then re-added, checked that in, but I still get the red symbol next to the file saying it is excluded from source control.

Ironically, when I right-click the file, it gives me the option to Exclude it, but not to include again.

Help!

Comment: Want to ask a question. How you are adding the file to your project again? With Add an Existing option ?

Comment: I tried right clicking the file in Solution Explorer - nothing.  Then in Team Explorer I removed then re-added the file via Source Control tab and the file is clearly part of the Source control now, yet me solution explorer still won't let me check it out (it still has the red mark next to the file saying it is excluded)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Steps to follow:

1. Select the appropriate file to reinclude.
2. Go to File -> Source Control -> Uncheck 'Exclude -FileName- from Source Control'.

Greetz

Comment: How did I miss that, Thank you :D

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to 'Project' -> click -> 'Show All Files'
2. Now all files are available in 'Solution Explorer'
3. Right click on the file you want to include in